# Assigning a value from a looped column name variable in a SELECT statement

Tags: t-sql, variables, select, local

I'm having a hard time trying to assign a field name and then place that into a SELECT statement in T SQL.  First - I want to get the SELECT statement to work without the convert error popping up, then I want the field value to be assigned to another variable.  My code that fails is below.

```
DECLARE @lid integer
DECLARE @lrid integer
DECLARE @pct integer
DECLARE @rds integer
SET @lid = 4
SET @lrid = 46
SET @pct = 75
SET @rds = 4

DECLARE @c integer --SIMPLE COUNTER
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(999) --RAW SCORE FIELD
DECLARE @cpct float --CALCULATED PERCENT
DECLARE @scrt integer --TOP SCORE
DECLARE @scrf nvarchar(10) --RAW SCORE FIELD
DECLARE @scrr integer --ROUND RAW SCORE
DECLARE @scrs integer --SUMMED RAW SCORE

--SET VARIABLES
SET @cpct = @pct * .01
SET @scrt = (SELECT points FROM league WHERE id = @lid)

--LOOP THROUGH SCORES FROM 1 ON UP
SET @c = 1
SET @scrs = 0
WHILE (@c <= 30)
BEGIN
  SET @scrf = 'round' + CAST(@c AS nvarchar(2))
  SELECT @scrr =(SELECT @scrf FROM league_lineup WHERE id = @lrid)
  SET @scrs = @scrs+@scrr

  IF @c > @rds
    PRINT 'ROUND ' + CAST(@c AS nvarchar(3)) + ' - SCORE: ' + CAST(@scrs AS nvarchar(5))
  SET @c = @c + 1
END
```

...doesn't work....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use dynamic query with output parameter in this situation:

Change

```
SELECT @scrr =(SELECT @scrf FROM league_lineup WHERE id = @lrid)
SET @scrs = @scrs+@scrr
```

to

```
DECLARE @sql = 'SELECT @scrr = ' + @scrf + ' FROM league_lineup WHERE id = @lrid'    
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@scrr int OUTPUT, @lrid int', @scrr OUTPUT, @lrid    
SET @scrs = @scrs+@scrr
```

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is that in TSQL, data is never evaluated as though it weren't data*.  That means this is what's happening is similar to that below:

```
SET @c = 25.48;
SET @scrf = 'round' + CAST(@c AS nvarchar(2));
```

The value of `@scrf` is now `'round25.48'`.  That means that this:

```
SELECT @scrr = (SELECT @scrf FROM league_lineup WHERE id = @lrid)
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
SELECT @scrr =(SELECT 'round25.48' FROM league_lineup WHERE id = @lrid)
```

Which means you're trying to assign the string (nvarchar) `'round25.48'`to `@scrr`, an integer variable.  So you get a conversion error.

You'll want to do something more like:

```
SELECT @scrr = (SELECT ROUND(@c) FROM league_lineup WHERE id = @lrid);
```

Finally, be careful with loops in SQL.  Chances are you don't actually need it.

---

*Data can be evaluated as though it were SQL with special functions like `EXEC()`, but those are exceptions.  Any anyways the data must be evaluated as an entire statement and not a fragment.

Comment: My apologies Bacon...My example was a bit misleading...the "round" in my example isn't actually meant to round anything...it is a part of my field name...like 'round1', "round2', etc...with what you put though - "maybe" that is the problem?  It is actually trying to "round" something?

Comment: @Chris In that case, no, the problem is that you're assigning a non-numeric data to a numeric-only field.  You say `DECLARE @scrr integer`.  You can't assign it anything other than a number between -2^31 and 2^31-1 anywhere in the query.  `@scrr` can't be an integer if you legitimately want it to get assigned the value `'round25.48'` (using my value of `@c`).

Comment: @Chris I think you will be further along to describe what it is you're trying to accomplish *overall*.  Post your entire query, post sample data, and post the results you'd like to get.  As it is, I'm basically just pointing out syntax errors.

Comment: Thank you - OK - I updated the code - I'm trying to get the value if the (round1, round2, and so on) columns and sum them up.  I know I could just sum them in a query - but I need to get the value at each increment.